# String or binary data would be truncated, insert to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

It's a runtime exception when I try to insert to a table, it was working before I added an update function.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rndID = new Random();
        int id = rndID.Next(100, 1000);

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IOHHC7K\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CityAppDB;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into UsersTB(User_ID, Full_Name, Email_Address, Phone_Number, Password) 
             values('" + id.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" +
             textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + 
             textBox5.Text + "')", connection);
        command.Connection.Open();

        if ((ISExisted(id)) && (CheckUserFullName(textBox2.Text)) && (IsValidEmail(textBox3.Text)) && (IsValidPhoneNumber(textBox4.Text)) && (IsValidPassword(textBox5.Text)))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();//String or binary data would be truncated
            MessageBox.Show("Added.");
            ShowAllUsers();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something wrong");
        }

        command.Connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What is datatype of User_Id and PhoneNumber in your database

Comment: Do you know that you can [edit] your question when you want to update something? And please, search about Sql Injection. Your code is a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: [User_ID] is nchar(5)

Comment: if your datatype is int then do not use single cot (')

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you are trying to update a value **which is too long** for the database column definition.

In your database, check the length of your `Full_Name`, `Email_Address`,`Phone_Number` and `Password` fields, let's say they are definded as `varchar[10]`, this error means that you are trying to update their value with a string longer than 10 characters,

Check the length of the values stored in one of your textboxes: `textBox2.Text`, `textBox3.Text`, `textBox4.Text` or `textBox5.Text`. One of them has a text which is longer than the database schema accepts.

**Solution 1**:
Increase the columns size in the database.

**Solution 2**:
Use `Textbox.MaxLength` to limit the user's input length.

Comment: one second i want to check my values, thank you for helping

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So increase the column size in the database and it will solve your broblem.

Comment: if i used for example: textBox4.MaxLenght = 10; is also good for my situation?

Comment: Yes it will. Check the other columns too.

Comment: No Problem, happy to help. Accepting my answer as correct will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sole purpose of the error is: your column size is specified lesser than the value you are supplying which can only be known from your table structure.

Again stop passing values using string concatenation rather use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection. Use [`SqlParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Your parameterized `INSERT` statement should look like

```
    string query = "insert into UsersTB(User_ID,Full_Name,Email_Address,Phone_Number,Password) values(@User_ID,@Full_Name,@Email_Address,@Phone_Number,@Password)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    command.Parameters.Add("@User_ID",id.ToString());
    command.Parameters.Add("@Full_Name",textBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Email_Address",textBox3.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Phone_Number",textBox4.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password",textBox5.Text);
```